# Multi-core versions of vapply and ddply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore, plyr

I've got such a code:

```
plot_cardinality <-function(data,name) {
    scT<-as(eclat(as(data.matrix(data)-1,"transactions"), parameter=list(support=0,minlen=1)),'data.frame')
    # count commas per data row in column items
    scT<-within(scT, size <- vapply(items, count.commas, 1))
    # use ddply to calculate min,mean,max support per size value
    u<-ddply(scT, .(size), summarise, m=mean(support), min=min(support),max=max(support))
    p <- ggplot(u) + geom_errorbar(data=u, aes(x=size, ymin=min, ymax=max))  + geom_point(aes(x=size,y=m), colour="red") +ggtitle(paste("Support for label occurence subsets\ndataset:",name))+xlab("Label subset cardinality")+ylab("Support of label subsets")
return(p)
}
```

Where count.commas is a simple comma counting function. This takes awfully long. How do I make this code use multiple cores for calculation? What is the best way to do it on a 16-core server? Which multicore solution should I use?

Comment: Parallelizing this isn't going to get you very far. You probably want to use `data.table` rather than `ddply`.

Comment: joran is correct, however, you can use the `.parallel=TRUE` argument to `ddply` after you load the package `doMC`.